# How to make a small QR with javascript

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a link I want to put in my barcode (google authenticator link). I am currently using the `JsBarcode` lib but it seems like the barcode is just too wide and the barcode scanner can't recognize it[image]

my configuration:

```
JsBarcode("#barcode", data,{
              displayValue: false,
              width: 1,
            });
```

I was wondering if there is a way to minimize it even more(because by their documentary the smallest size is 1) or a different way to solve this

Comment: Obviously a barcode that currently has lines with 1 pixel width, cannot be made more narrow. Some lines would then (have to) disappear. So you need a different way. However, questions for suggesting libraries is off topic here.

Comment: @trincot Fair, I rephrased the question

Comment: @Patch can you provide a little more context on what you're trying to solve?  Ie, are you looking to have a mobile device (ie, is this your "barcode scanner"?) read the google authenticator link barcode off a video screen, and then pass this link to the mobile browser?

Comment: @JonTrent In the backend, I have the generated URI for the barcode. I am getting the barcode URI with an ajax request I want the user to be able to scan the barcode that's all. The reason I can't do it now it's because it's too wide(because the URI is long).

Comment: @Patch, so to clarify via scenario... you have a user at a workstation with a browser that makes an ajax call to a server.  The server returns a URI, which the browser then uses JSBarcode to convert to a barcode, displayed in the user's workstation browser.  You are then looking to have the user, via their mobile device, scan the barcoded URI, which opens up the mobile browser, which presumably makes a call back to the server.  Correct?

Comment: @JonTrent yeah but the end part is this: the user scans the code in the google auth app in his phone  and that's it. I already put the secret key in the db before hand. Anyway, I fixed it. I'll upload my solution tommorow, I did use a different lib

Comment: @Patch, glad to hear you solved it.  I was going to recommend the use of QR codes, which are a bit more condensed, but wasn't quite sure of your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up using a [different library](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/).

```
Link:

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='qrcode.min.js') }}" defer></script> // jinja2
```

---

```
JS code:

    var qrcode = new QRCode(document.querySelector("#barcode"), { // have to select a query like this
                  text: data,
                  width: 128,
                  height: 128,
                  colorDark : "#000000",
                  colorLight : "#ffffff",
                  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
                });
```

The HTML code has an empty `div`. 
Result:[image](without the red marker ofcurse)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make qrcodes in javascript, then I highly recommend http://bwip-js.metafloor.com/ (I am the author of the project).  It supports both normal and micro qrcodes.

For example, from the browser, you pass in a canvas element (or its ID) and it resizes and draws the barcode to the canvas:

```js
try {
    // The return value is the canvas element
    let canvas = bwipjs.toCanvas('mycanvas', {
            bcid:        'qrcode',   // Barcode type
            text:        url,        // Text to encode
            scale:       2,          // scaling factor
        });
} catch (e) {
    // `e` may be a string or Error object
}
```

Comment: It looks great! But I ended up finding a different solution. I am going to upload the answer that I did because I know for sure that it worked. +1

Answer (score -1):

You should use another encoding, check this generator using the same library : https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/generator/

Pharmacode or ITF produce smaller barcodes

Comment: my link would be "Not valid data for this barcode type!" if I used any other type